# Append an excel sheet to another using NPOI

Tags: excel, apache-poi, npoi

I am trying to append the data from multiple sheets in the same workbook and append them to the first sheet.

Here's what I have been able to accomplish:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    HSSFWorkbook hssfwb;
    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
       hssfwb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    } 
    var BaseSheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < workbook.NumberOfSheets; i++)
    {
       AddRowsToBaseSheet(BaseSheet, workbook.GetSheetAt(i), workbook);
    }
}

  private void AddRowsToBaseSheet(ISheet BaseSheet, ISheet sheet, HSSFWorkbook workbook)
    {
        var temp = sheet.GetRowEnumerator();
        while (temp.MoveNext())
        {
            HSSFRow sourceRow = (HSSFRow)temp.Current;
            HSSFRow destinationRow = (HSSFRow)BaseSheet.CreateRow(BaseSheet.LastRowNum + 1);
            CopyRow(workbook, sourceRow, destinationRow);
        }
    }

private void CopyRow(HSSFWorkbook workbook, IRow sourceRow, IRow destinationRow)
    {

        // Loop through source columns to add to new row
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceRow.LastCellNum; i++)
        {
            // Grab a copy of the old/new cell
            ICell oldCell = sourceRow.GetCell(i);
            ICell newCell = destinationRow.CreateCell(i);

            // If the old cell is null jump to next cell
            if (oldCell == null)
            {
                newCell = null;
                continue;
            }



            // Set the cell data type
            newCell.SetCellType(oldCell.CellType);

            // Set the cell data value
            switch (oldCell.CellType)
            {
                case CellType.Blank:
                    newCell.SetCellValue(oldCell.StringCellValue);
                    break;
                case CellType.Boolean:
                    newCell.SetCellValue(oldCell.BooleanCellValue);
                    break;
                case CellType.Error:
                    newCell.SetCellErrorValue(oldCell.ErrorCellValue);
                    break;
                case CellType.Formula:
                    newCell.SetCellFormula(oldCell.CellFormula);
                    break;
                case CellType.Numeric:
                    newCell.SetCellValue(oldCell.NumericCellValue);
                    break;
                case CellType.String:
                    newCell.SetCellValue(oldCell.RichStringCellValue);
                    break;
                case CellType.Unknown:
                    newCell.SetCellValue(oldCell.StringCellValue);
                    break;
            }
        }



    }
```

I might be doing a foolish mistake, or is there any other library for the same?

Converting into dataset wont work in this case as the columns are not related

Comment: Where are you writing to the output file?

Comment: the output file is the same, but in the first sheet, all the sheets are not being appended in the first sheet, thats what i am aiming to achieve

Comment: To expand on what @DariusX. mentioned in his comment, you need to save your changes by writing to the output file. Currently you are just adding the new rows in memory. These changes will be discarded when the program completes because you have not written them out to the file.

Comment: Works perfectly :)
I thought it NPOI refers to the excel, but it actually creates an in memory representation of it